# Why do I need the past, not the past perfect, here?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, used-to

> Capital expenditure of their company in the year 2001 _______ clearly below the spending in the year 2000 when they _______ about half the investments for the concept conversion.

A) used to be / had used (which I picked)

B) was / used  (the correct answer)

Can anybody explain why my answer is wrong?

Comment: *Used to be* is for situations that have changed. If I say *I used to live in Paris*, it means I don't live there now. The capital expenditure of the company *in 2001* cannot change because it is in the past, so it has to be *was*.

Answer (score 1):

The expenditure of a company in a past year is a basic fact and there is no reason not to use *was*. You would use *used to be* of an ongoing situation. *The company used to be based in London but has now moved to Manchester.*

Comment: Yeah, "used to be" is not idiomatic in the above, but "had used" is ungrammatical.  Remove the "unnecessary" (from a syntactic standpoint) words and you'd get "Capital expenditure had used clearly below the spending ..." -- clearly nonsense.